# Is there a way to cache Spring <mvc:resources> files in memory?

Tags: java, spring, caching, resources, static-files

Suppose I have bound all urls to Spring dispatcher servlet, and set up some `.css` and `.js` directories with `<mvc:resources>` in mvc Spring namespace.

**Can I cache those static Spring resources in memory to avoid hitting disk on user request?**

(Note that I am not asking about HTTP caching like `Not Modified` response and also don't mean Tomcat static files caching or setting up another webserver in front of Java webserwer, just Spring solution)

Comment: Doesn't `cache-period` answer to your question ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan As I know it involve further client request and HTTP response (not modified), but if new client wants download files (visits page), then read from disk happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as you say that you want to `cache` the entire content of your underlying target resource, you have to cache its `byte[]` from `inputStream`.

Since `<mvc:resources>` is backed by `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` there is no stops to write your own sub-class and use it directly instead of that custom tag.

And implement your caching logic just within overrided `writeContent` method:

```
public class CacheableResourceHttpRequestHandler extends ResourceHttpRequestHandler {

        private Map<URL, byte[]> cache = new HashMap<URL, byte[]>();

        @Override
        protected void writeContent(HttpServletResponse response, Resource resource) throws IOException {
            byte[] content = this.cache.get(resource.getURL());
            if (content == null) {
                content = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(resource.getInputStream());
                this.cache.put(resource.getURL(), content);
            }
            StreamUtils.copy(content, response.getOutputStream());
        }

    }
```

And use it from spring config as generic bean:

```
<bean id="staticResources" class="com.my.proj.web.CacheableResourceHttpRequestHandler">
    <property name="locations" value="/public-resources/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <value>/resources/**=staticResources</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```